# Python - search for string, extract number from line and append to list

Tags: python, cad, step

I am working with a STEP file format which I want to parse, extract information and store it in arrays so I can call upon and perform mathematical operations on them later in the program.

Below is an example of the data I am working with (advanced_face references face_outer_bound later in the data file:

```
#12 = ADVANCED_FACE ( 'NONE', ( #194 ), #326, .F. ) ;
...
#194 = FACE_OUTER_BOUND ( 'NONE', #159, .T. ) ;
```

Here's what I have come up with so far:

```
import re

with open('TestSlot.STEP', 'r') as step_file:
        data = step_file.readlines()

NF = 0
faces = []
for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        if re.search("ADVANCED_FACE", line):
                NF = NF + 1
                advface = re.compile('#\d+')
                advfaceresult = advface.match(line)
                faces.append(advfaceresult.group())

print("Face IDs =", faces)
print("Number of faces, NF =", NF)
```

This gives the output:

```
Face IDs = ['#12', '#73', '#99', '#131', '#181', '#214', '#244', 
'#273', '#330', '#358']
Number of faces, NF = 10
```

How would I go about stripping the regex match so only the number is appended to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group within regex and convert directly string '12' to number 12 before append to faces list
`advface = re.compile('#(\d+)')
advfaceresult = advface.match(line)
faces.append(int(advfaceresult.group(1)))`

the result will be Face IDs = [12, ...]

Also solution can be reached by

```
import re
ifile = r'TestSlot.STEP'
with open(ifile) as f:
    text = f.read()  # read all text
    faces_txt = re.findall(r'#(\d+) = ADVANCED_FACE.*;', text)
    #  get all groups by re
    faces = [int(face) for face in faces_txt]   # convert to int
    print('Face IDs = ', faces)
    print('Number of faces, NF =', len(faces))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Worked perfectly. Just so I can understand where it is coming from, why is the group number 1?

Comment: Also as the file format is hierarchical, I was thinking it might be a better method to create list for each face. So search for first match of ADVANCED_FACE, append ID.. then search for that face's FACE_OUTER_BOUND, append ID.. and so on until I have a list defining each face.

Any idea how I would go about it that way instead?

Comment: group(1) means get group from regex in (), group 0 is all regexp
if we have re.findall('#(\d) = ADVANCED_FACE (.*);')
group(0) is all text
group(1) is (\d)
group(2) is string ( 'NONE', ( #194 ), #326, .F. )
In this case for getting all face it seems to me good way will be

`faces_txt = re.findall(r'#(\d+) = (.*)(.*;', text)
    #  return list of couples group(1), group(2) use ( as feature to end of face name
    faces = [int(face), face_name for face_id, face_name in faces_txt]`